# TypeScript Api Manager and session handling

Tags: typescript, rest, model

I'm building an Api manager using typescript for an API I want to integrate to. There are a couple of considerations here:

1. I have models, for example: `Student` Model. This model is allowed to login to get a session token like this:

   const student = Student.login('username', 'password');

   const courses = teacher.getCourses(student.id);

   ...

This login method would be implemented like this:

```
class Student {
    ...
    private token: string = undefined;
    ...
    public static login(username:string, password:string): Promise<Student> {
        return MyManager.post('https://apihost/student/login', {username, password})
            .then((res) => {return new Student(res.data)});
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, let's suppose the user wants to see a list of courses the student is currently in, the `getCourses` method would be called and it would be implemented like this:

```
public getCourses = () => {
    return MyManager.get("/courses", {token: this.token})...
}
```

Ok this is the issue right here...

- How do I save the token in the ApiManager to use it later?
- Should I use a Singleton for this? `setToken(token)` in login success.
- **How do I share this token and ApiManager with other classes like `Teacher`?**

What if I want to do:

```
const teacher = new Teacher();
teacher.getCourses(student.id);
...

class Teacher {
    ...
    public getCourses() {
        return MyManager.get("/courses", {token: ???????}) 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I've being looking around and I think that I need something like an orm/odm `Connection` class to store the token, and then my models could just inherit from a ManagerClass or something. What do you think about this?